# Why is react Strict Mode breaking Material UI theme change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react application that uses material ui

My application has a dark theme toggle which changes the theme via material ui `createTheme()` https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/.

However, when i toggle between themes within React.StrictMode it breaks.

**index.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Demo />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Please see below link and toggle the checkbox for the demo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-16044

However if you remove the <React.StrictMode> it will work

**index.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Demo />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Can someone tell me why this is occuring, it seems like there is some underlining issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what “it breaks” means?

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you see the codesandbox link i put in my OP? add the React.StrictMode element to index.tsx and then toggle the checkbox in the sidebar and look what happens, its quite difficult to describe so thats why i porivded the codesandbox or check the updated link

Comment: v4 of Material-UI is not compatible with StrictMode. v5 (currently in beta) is.

Comment: @Kay I did see it, but was on mobile. FWIW, I would have described the issue as "theme doesn't switch correctly" and included the React and MaterialUI versions (versions are always a good idea to include) which would be enough to track down the [known issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23334) even on mobile :)